# Python - import module using variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, module

My project is in below structure.

```
myapp/
    pack1/
        module1.py
        module1.py
     pack2/
        module3.py
        module4.py 
        .
        .
        moduleN.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

I want to import a module from pack2 and my current working file is pack1/module1.py.

pack2 will have many modules and i need to get them by using a variable.

i have tried `exec('from pack2 import module3')` and `module = importlib.import_module(self.pack2, package=None).`.

My code,

```
class ParseData:
    def __init__(self, page_res, domain):
       self.page_response = page_res
       self.domain_ = domain

    def listing_details(self):
        import importlib
        module = importlib.import_module(self.domain_, package=None)
        from module import listing_page
```

I got ended up with error,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/LRI/sample_parser.py", line 16, in <module>
    get_listing_data(js)
  File "D:/LRI/sample_parser.py", line 7, in get_listing_data
    webPage.listing_details()
  File "D:\LRI\geoScraper\parser_module.py", line 12, in listing_details
    from module import listing_page
ImportError: No module named 'module'
```

Though these seems working i could not find a way to access the imported module further.

Any guidance can help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ManojKengudelu updated question with error message.

Comment: Update your questing with the code snippets

Comment: @EMKAY updated.

Comment: there could also be indentation error in your code. Please verify `python -tt script.py`

Comment: @ManojKengudelu I am sure that i do not have any indentation error. My question is not about the error. It is about how to perform the action.

Comment: `function = getattr(module, listing_page)` instead of `from module import listing_page`

Comment: try this : 'from {folder where module exist}.module import listing_page' @SmashGuy

Comment: @Erwan it is not working. `NameError: name 'listing_page' is not defined` is the response.

Comment: @EMKAY should i use that inside exec()?

Comment: You have to worry about your entrypoint how did you launch your script ? (`python3 module1.py` or `python3 foo.py`)

Comment: i will initiate from `foo.py`. That script will get references from other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After summing up all the responses and my attempts finally this worked for me.

```
domain = __import__(domain) 
func = getattr(domain, 'check')
```

And i had to change the file structure like,

```
myapp/
    pack1/
        module1.py
        module1.py
    module3.py
    module4.py 
    .
    .
    moduleN.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```